# No network connection in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 and updated all packages using:

`apt-get update`
`apt-get upgrade`

I have installed and configured `Gitlab` from their Omnibus package.

For two days, I used the server without issues.

However, today I cannot connect to my local network.

Ubuntu stucks for 5 minutes in the boot screen waiting for the following to finish:

`start job raise network interfaces`

When Ubuntu started:

`sudo service networking status` display a red `inactive` text along other texts.

I have used:

`sudo service networking restart`, `sudo ifconfig enp1s0 up` and `sudo dhclient enp1s0`

Still nothing working.

When I use `ipconfig` i see two intrefaces: `lo` and `enp1s0`

When I use `ip addr show` no ip address for `enp1s0` is displayed. Which was not the case before. I had used this same command to get the ip address of my server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your server isn't able to get a DHCP assigned IP address. Have you checked your DHCP server?

You could also try a static IP addresss (probably best for a server anyway) see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Comment: I have tried to configure a static ip as per your link documentation. `ip addr show` shows info of my static configuration as if it was connecting but no actual network connection.